# Testing Multilayer Perceptron

Tags: java, neural-network

I'm very new to Neural Networks and I'm still trying to understand the concepts. I've seen  implementations of MLP in different programming languages. According to what I've read, the goal is to find the weights which will make the outputs match the expected.

What if I already have the weights from the trained network? How do I make use of those weights to test the network? Say I have new inputs for the testing set, how do I use the trained network to look for matches from the training set? (I'm doing image recognition) There are available libraries but I want to at least know how things work. I've read and scanned through a few but I can't seem the find where the testing method is.

I'm reading articles about MLP but I still lack knowledge. I badly want to understand this part. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you already decided on your MLP library? I'd suggest to read up on the different libraries, pick one that can do what you want, and then read up more on how it actually works.
Right now you question is quite vague.

Comment: Neuroph does everything and image recognition itself, but I want to set my own parameters to be used for testing. I originally plan to make use of this [java implementation](http://www.ncorpus.com/aydingurel/codes_java_neural/java_neural_multilayer_perceptron.html) but I can't find the testing method. It does basically what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is supervised learning with the training set. The Network learns (the weights) (e.g. by backpropagation) to classify the training set correctly.

When you present a new input to your network, the hope is that the learned weights lead to a correct classification of the new input.

Comment: Ohh. How exactly do I classify the new input given the weights? The implementation I've seen goes this way: input training set -> obtain weights. For testing, does it go the same way? I obtain the weights and compare it with the weights from the training set?

Comment: You use the weights learned while training (from the training set) and than never change them again. The hope is, that this weights will lead the network to classify new input correctly, because it is similar to an element of the training set.

Comment: Ohhhhh. Ok. Im somehow being enlightened. But how would I know which element from the training set is my testing set similar to? I mean, after inputting the testing set to the network and making use of the weights from the training set, the output would be? Sorry if I have so many questions. O.O

Comment: Most times you learn an attribute (ore a few attributes) for all elements of the test set. E.g. Is there a house on the picture? yes/no. Such a network will answer to a new input with 'yes' or 'no' which means it 'believes' there is also a house on the new image or not.

Comment: Say I have n classifications. the output could be any number from 1 to n? Thanks for taking time in answering my questions.

Comment: I think now you got the idea.